# how to enable hyper-v in windows 10 home edition for running windows phone 8.1 emulator

Tags: emulation, hyper-v

I want to run emulator in visual studio 2015 . but i cant able to enable it in my windows 10 home edition , because **there is no option in (windows on or off feature)** . my laptop support **slat**.. And i also enable visualization technology from bios setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V is not available in Windows 10 Home. You have to either upgrade to Windows 10 Pro 64bit or use a 3rd party option like VMWare or Virtual Box.

Comment: Thank you _belinus_ . I got it

Answer (score 0):

Yes this works on Windows 10 professional, however on my system (Lenovo idea pad yoga Intel i5, my TaskBar, InternetExplorer , Edge , restart and FireFox all became unstable until I switched Hyper V  off again.